# Select from two tables and count how many comments has post

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make query which will show me the post and the number of comments that have this post. This is the query but I got blank page

```
$result = $pdo->query("
    SELECT posts.*, comments.count(*)
    FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id
    WHERE ( comments.post_id
          IN ( 
                SELECT MAX( post_id ) 
                FROM comments
                GROUP BY post_id
          )
    )
    OR ( 
          NOT EXISTS 
          (
                SELECT NULL 
                FROM comments
                WHERE comments.post_id = posts.post_id
          )
    )
    AND posts.post_id = :post_id
"); 

if ($result->execute(array(':post_id'=>$_GET['post_id'])))
{
      // rest of the code
}
```

I'm not even sure that the query is proper constructed. The goal is to show the post and count number of comments. Like
`This post have 3 comments`

When I execute this code I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

which occurs on this line:

`if ($result->execute(array(':post_id'=>$_GET['post_id'])))`

Update: **Final and work form**

```
SELECT posts . * , COUNT( comments.comment_id ) AS total
FROM posts, comments
WHERE  posts.post_id = comments.post_id
AND posts.post_id=:post_id
```

Comment: Are there any errors given? Ensure you have error reporting on in order to know if there have been.

Comment: the error is `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object` on line `if ($result->execute(array(':post_id'=>$_GET['post_id'])))`

Comment: When I execute the query in phpmyadmin the error is `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM posts LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id WHERE ( com' at line 1`

Comment: You have an issue with your query. Might be worth looking in the manual to see what the issue is. [The SQL COUNT docs](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) might be relevant.

Comment: You should replace `comments.count(*)` by `COUNT(comments.*)`

Comment: Ok, I fixed it with `COUNT( comments.comment_id ) ` but there is still problem in `AND post_id = :post_id` statement.

Comment: I found the problem there but still ... doesn't work. When is `and comments.post_id = 1` is working but when is `and comments.post_id = :post_id` it is showing me this error -> `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`

Comment: I have make it to work. I've updated also my question with the working query in case someone need it. Thank's for the help!

Answer (score 1):

try with query

```
SELECT posts.*,COUNT(comments.`post_id`) AS totalcomment
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments   ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id
```